non-integer candela measurements and candela manipulation
What was the oldest way to quantify or measure candelas or control it as as an independent variable (luminous intensity)?

Candela was only proposed as a unit in 1937. Are you asking about measuring luminous intensity generally or specifically measuring it in candelas?

the generally control/measurement is the question.

See Treece, History and Measurement of the Base and Derived Units:"To determine candlepower of a light source, a standard candle was burned next to the light source of interest, separated by an opaque divider... The unknown light source was then moved back and forth on the other side of the divider, changing the distance to the screen until the intensity of light striking the screen on both sides of the divider was judged to be the same. The candlepower... was then calculated using the inverse square relationship."
